# Having trouble looping with ngFor

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm pretty new to Angular 2 and I've reached a impasse in my project. I want to use the `*ngFor` directive to loop through an array of objects to display its contents in a 'list view' using `<div *ngFor="let gig of gigs">`. At the same time, I want to support a slideshow view where users can click 'back' or 'next' to navigate. The problem is, getting slideshow to work requires defaulting to first slide, the first object in the array:

```
this.initialSlide = 0;
this.gigs = this.resume[this.initialSlide];
```

My data is stored in `this.resume`: `[[{Object1}],[{Object2}],[{Object3}]]`. I was trying to  get the 'list view' to work by setting `gigs` property to `this.resume`, but the view was blank. I think it's because its iterating over arrays and an index needs to be specified. When I do specify an index though, the default slideshow trips up since it's set to index 0 already (above). I included my code below, please let me know if I need to clarify.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-app-resume',
  styleUrls: ['./app-resume.component.css'],
  template: `
<div ng-click='check(count)'>
<br>
<div *ngFor="let gig of gigs">
<div class = "size">
<h2>{{gig.company}}</h2>
<br>
<h3>{{gig.Date}}</h3>
<ul *ngFor="let duty of gig.duties">
<li>{{duty}}</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
<button (click)="cycle(-1)">back</button>
<button (click)="cycle(1)">next</button>
<button (click)="cycle('all')">full list view</button>
</div>
`
})

export class AppResumeComponent implements OnInit {
    resume;
  message;
  initialSlide;
  gigs;
  gig;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.resume = [
        [{company:'Heavy', position: 'Tech Contributor', Date:'October 2016 - December 2016','duties':['Identify, research and publish stories that will generate significant organic traffic','Manage all aspects of the publishing process on WordPress','Analyze data from Dataminr, Google AdWords and Google Trends to find trending topics']}],
        [{company:'Steele Consulting', position:'Media Coordinator', Date:'April 2013 - October 2015','duties':['Boosted organic traffic to website by 34 percent through SEO and revamped blog','Launched whatasteele radio, the podcast about entrepreneurship in real estate']}],
        [{company:'Wochit',position: 'Creator',Date:'April 2015 - October 2015','duties':['Produced videos that made our YouTube channel’s Top 25 for a subscriber base of over 25K people','Internally recognized twice for exceeding the threshold of videos created']}],
        [{company:'Inc.',position: 'Editorial Intern',Date:'March 2015 - June 2015','duties':['Created the 2015 Best in Class Awards page, a guide to the nation’s best designed products','Internally recognized twice for exceeding the threshold of videos created','Wrote 40 posts about start-up conferences, business executives, and national news']}],
        [{company:'The Chicago Tribune',position: 'Assistant Video Producer',Date:'Sept 2014 - Dec 2014','duties':['Shot & Produced breaking news videos and used Chartbeat to promote videos on landing page']}]
    ]
    this.initialSlide = 0;
    this.gigs = this.resume[this.initialSlide];
}

  cycle(d){
    if  (d == 'all'){
      console.log('all initiated')
      this.gigs = this.resume
    }
    else{
        this.initialSlide += d 
        if (this.initialSlide >= this.resume.length )
        {this.initialSlide -= 1}
        else if (this.initialSlide < 0)
        {this.initialSlide += 1}
        else{
            this.gigs = this.resume[this.initialSlide]}
    }
  };  }
```

EDIT: i'm afraid I haven't been clear on what I expect for my project. I hope this illustration along with a plunker link makes things clearer :

Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/PKDH9tDLHnjrK4flyK1A?p=preview
[image]

Comment: Your question is not clear, though i see some issue in your code. if the button `full list view` get clicked code will give you error as you are assigning whole `resume` object to `gigs` inside `cycle()` function.

Comment: i'm not seeing the error on inspection window when I click full list view. I just get a blank page. That's why i enclosed every object with `[]` because *ngFor only accepts arrays

Comment: can you make a plunker for the your question, because the question is not clear and i still don't know what problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: OK, I've uploaded the files for the plunkr here: https://plnkr.co/edit/PKDH9tDLHnjrK4flyK1A?p=preview

Comment: thank you, I now understand the error `NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.` referred to ` this.gigs = this.resume[this.initialSlide];` instead of the resume array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is correct except "Array of array". The way you want to display the information of `resume` required you to put the "company information" as  Object rather than array in `resume`.

```
this.resume = [
        {company:'Heavy', position: 'Tech Contributor', Date:'October 2016 - December 2016','duties':['Identify, research and publish stories that will generate significant organic traffic','Manage all aspects of the publishing process on WordPress','Analyze data from Dataminr, Google AdWords and Google Trends to find trending topics']},
        {company:'Steele Consulting', position:'Media Coordinator', Date:'April 2013 - October 2015','duties':['Boosted organic traffic to website by 34 percent through SEO and revamped blog','Launched whatasteele radio, the podcast about entrepreneurship in real estate']},
        {company:'Wochit',position: 'Creator',Date:'April 2015 - October 2015','duties':['Produced videos that made our YouTube channel’s Top 25 for a subscriber base of over 25K people','Internally recognized twice for exceeding the threshold of videos created']},
        {company:'Inc.',position: 'Editorial Intern',Date:'March 2015 - June 2015','duties':['Created the 2015 Best in Class Awards page, a guide to the nation’s best designed products','Internally recognized twice for exceeding the threshold of videos created','Wrote 40 posts about start-up conferences, business executives, and national news']},
        {company:'The Chicago Tribune',position: 'Assistant Video Producer',Date:'Sept 2014 - Dec 2014','duties':['Shot & Produced breaking news videos and used Chartbeat to promote videos on landing page']}
    ]
```

But you need to change the way you are assigning the value to `this.gigs` variable. 
Instead of writing

```
 this.gigs = this.resume[this.initialSlide];
```

you should do :

```
this.gigs = [this.resume[this.initialSlide]];
```

but when you want to show the whole list then directly asign the value of `resume` to `gigs`

```
 this.gigs = this.resume
```

Here is the working code:

https://plnkr.co/edit/YmlGqPca5SCMe66nagvd?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

this.resume in your current code is an array of arrays. You have to convert it to array of objects:

```
this.resume = [
    {company:'Heavy', position: 'Tech Contributor', Date:'October 2016 - December 2016','duties':['Identify, research and publish stories that will generate significant organic traffic','Manage all aspects of the publishing process on WordPress','Analyze data from Dataminr, Google AdWords and Google Trends to find trending topics']},
    {company:'Steele Consulting', position:'Media Coordinator', Date:'April 2013 - October 2015','duties':['Boosted organic traffic to website by 34 percent through SEO and revamped blog','Launched whatasteele radio, the podcast about entrepreneurship in real estate']},
    {company:'Wochit',position: 'Creator',Date:'April 2015 - October 2015','duties':['Produced videos that made our YouTube channel’s Top 25 for a subscriber base of over 25K people','Internally recognized twice for exceeding the threshold of videos created']},
    {company:'Inc.',position: 'Editorial Intern',Date:'March 2015 - June 2015','duties':['Created the 2015 Best in Class Awards page, a guide to the nation’s best designed products','Internally recognized twice for exceeding the threshold of videos created','Wrote 40 posts about start-up conferences, business executives, and national news']},
    {company:'The Chicago Tribune',position: 'Assistant Video Producer',Date:'Sept 2014 - Dec 2014','duties':['Shot & Produced breaking news videos and used Chartbeat to promote videos on landing page']}
]
```

This change should make your code work

Answer (score 1):

After looking at the plunker we can make the `full list view` by changing the `cycle()` function as follows.

```
cycle(d){
if  (d == 'all'){
  console.log('all initiated')
  this.gigs = [];
  // reduce resume array to single dimensional array
  this.resume.forEach(val => this.gigs.push(val[0]));
}
else{
    this.initialSlide += d 
    if (this.initialSlide >= this.resume.length )
    {this.initialSlide -= 1}
    else if (this.initialSlide < 0)
    {this.initialSlide += 1}
    else{

        this.gigs = this.resume[this.initialSlide]
        }

 }
};
```

here is the [updated plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/UCAzA0TaiPLWSjpXVdgy?p=preview)

> There are many possible solution for your requirement, and this is one with the minimal changes to the code.